# Gender and forms of "рыба-кит"

Tags: лексикон, род, composite-nouns

What is the gender of the word "рыба-кит"? Should I say "огромная рыба-кит" or "огромный рыба-кит"?

Also, how should I change it if it is not in nominative case?

Gramota.ru suggests that рыба-кит is not used in any other forms, but as a native speaker I could easily imagine a context like "Богатырь победил рыб...-кит...".

Comment: Ah, an interesting question! On one hand, in Ershov's tale the character is clearly masculine: "«Ладно, ладно, рыба-кит!» - Наш Иван **ему** кричит." On the other hand, anything other than "Богатырь победил рыбу-кит" does not sound natural.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Sounds like a valid answer to me, which could only be improved by providing some statistics on how often рыба-кит is referred to as a masculine noun (and how many times it is mentioned at all)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Considering that there are no gender-differentiated versions of `рыба-кит`, the author might have used `ему` simply to indicate the gender of the fish in question, similarly to how one could use `ему` with `рыба` (as there is no `рыб` or `рыбиха` to differentiate between genders of an imaginary fish family).

Comment: By the way, is it just me, or would "Богатырь победил рыбу-кита" sound almost as natural as "Богатырь победил рыбу-кит"?

Comment: @PhilipSeyfi Apparently, no: I asked my wife and daughters this very question this morning, and they all replied that `победил рыбу-кит` sounds right, while `победил рыбу-кита` does not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Feeling-based answer is: *рыба-кит* is feminine and only the first part of the word is declined:

```
рыба-кит
рыбы-кит
рыбе-кит
etc.
```

This is in analogy with *меч-рыба*.

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле, хотя это и не правильно, русские скорее будут говорить так:

- Кто? Рыба-кит
- Кого? Рыбу-кита
- Кому? Рыбе-киту
- Кем? Рыбой-китом
- О ком? О Рыбе-ките

Т.е. слова склонять можно раздельно.

По поводу рода - я затрудняюсь ответить, скорее женский, так как первично определение "рыба", а "кит" - вторично.

Comment: А каким источником вы пользуетесь, говоря, что рыба-кит изменяется так?

Comment: Кстати, в оригинале (у Пушкина) там: "Чудо-юдо рыба-кит". Т.е. ещё и средний род в определении =)

Comment: Ольга, такие слова никто не знает, как спрягать. Они и появлялись как художественный вымысел для одноразового использования в стихах. Правило тут не придумать, разные люди будут говорить по-разному.

Comment: В таком случае, почему вы решили, что люди предпочтут один вариант другому?

Comment: Ну ведь предпочитают. Можно погуглить "Рыбу-кита", не один человек считает верным именно такое написание. Для вас, наверное, русский родной, как и для меня, согласитесь, русский человек может непонятное слово просклонять как угодно. Например: Слышал песню, где поют "Феличита"? Или: "Ты эту, феличиту, слышал"? Демонстративно пренебрежительно. С китом всё аналогично.

Comment: А вы можете включить статистику из Гугла в ваш ответ? Потому что интуиция хороша для формулирования гипотез, а статистика бы ее хорошо подтвердила бы.

Comment: @Игорь: where exactly did Pushkin use this?

Comment: @Игорь фраза "Чудо-юдо рыба-кит" использовалась Ершовым в Коньке-Горбунке: http://www.planetaskazok.ru/drstihiotech/konekgorbunoksth?start=6 - _Тут конёк на хвост вбегает, // К перьям близко прилегает // И что мочи есть кричит: // «Чудо-юдо Рыба-кит! // Оттого твои мученья, // Что без божия веленья // Проглотил ты средь морей // Три десятка кораблей..._

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the gender of the whole word is defined by the part describing animated, live object, which is not necessarily the first part. The example mentioned above describes this idea quite well: both *рыба-кит* and *меч-рыба* are feminine. As well as *девушка-виденье*, *бой-баба* etc.
More precisely, the declension would be logically connected with the object part of the word (рыба). The definition part does not affect the declension and has **gender-dependent** morphology itself: if the object part has a masculine gender, the definition part is affected by declension; if the object part has a feminine gender, the definitive part stays indefinite. I.e. *рыба-меч, рыбы-меч, рыбу-меч*, but *конь-огонь, коня-огня*; *меч-кладенец, меча-кладенца*.

Comment: It would be interesting to know, where this rule comes from? Or is it just a tendency?

Comment: Вообще, если быть точным, то склонение логически будет связано с морфологией той части составного слова, которая является объектом (рыба). Та часть, которая является свойством (меч, кит) на склонение влиять не должна, да и сама вряд ли подлежит морфологическим изменениям.

Comment: Эту информацию лучше добавить в ответ.

Comment: КуЪ has a good point on definition parts with a feminine gender. They are affected by declension in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку чудо-юдо рыба-кит рождена в стихах и в фольклоре и применяется только в сказочном контексте, то мне кажется, что важнее сохранить стихотворный размер, распевность, народный стиль (которому в литературе позволительно появляться в нарочито безграмотном виде), чем пытаться соблюдать какие-либо правила языка, поэтому "чудо", "юдо" и "рыбу" - склонять, "кит" - оставлять без изменений.

**Правило** я бы так сформулировал: если существительные одного рода, то склонять оба, а если разного, то только главное из них, например:

> рыбу-пилу, рыбе-пиле

но

> рыбу-молот, рыбе-молот.

Comment: Кстати, кажется мне, что это чудовище было придумано Козловым в Коньке-Горбунке, а не народом.

Comment: Что касается чудовища, то, скорее всего, ноги тут растут из библейской истории про пророка Иону.

Comment: @Olga: Kozlov ?

Comment: Yershov, of course